# Is there a programming language that is designed for compiling into (large) neural networks?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I thought about this a while ago, that maybe there should be (or is already) a programming language that actually compiles into a big neural network, that ideally, would scale very well for parallel computing and has some other NN specific advantages, like learning.

It should be possible, as shown in a paper i found a while ago. The people wrote a compiler for pascal(called jaNNet) that compiles into a neural network. It seems it has alot of limitations and does not work very well with recursion, though:

http://blob.lri.fr/publication/tcs.pdf

Are there any other projects that try to write a compiler for a specific language *designed* for neural networks?

I am also thinking of features like embedded optimization functions. So i can write lets say, a "module" where I specifiy some inputs and some outputs and define a function that describes the fitness of the module, so the compiler (and later the runtime) can constantly optimize the "module".

These modules should be easily plugged together to form a bigger program. Obviously statements such as ifs and loops, variables and functions etc should be possible.

I wonder if there were no such thing, because I assume this would make development of robots and bigger AI-projects alot easier or at least faster.

Another question I ask myself if such a compiled program could beat a traditional program when it comes to parallel execution and performance.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of a programming language for developing ANNs. It seems to me that you might want, not a full-fledged programming language, but a domain-specific language. With a complete programming language you have to deal with input and output and program control, etc. It's a lot of work in order to get the benefit of saying `theseNeurons feedForwardTo thoseNeurons`.

OTOH, a domain-specific language would be, for most implementation languages, difficult to separately compile towards the GPU, which I think is the great (potential) win for an ANN-specific language (that is, ANNs are a good match for highly parallel architectures, but GPGPU and other high-performance programming techniques are very specialized).

Comment: Perhaps a DSL that uses GPGPU or similar as its target would be a possibility?

Comment: Ideally you'd like a DSL in a very end-user friendly language such as Ruby or Python but be able to generate very specialized high-performance code. It's not the normal use-case for implementing a DSL. But it would be very nice.

Comment: I actually thought of a traditional programming language, not only designed to specify an ANN but that can be used to write normal programs, like C++ or Java.

Comment: Mainly because I "guess" one can benefit of the parallel nature of ANNs and easy integration of learning parts in the program and naturally good platform indepedence. Let me know if this a bad idea or why this would be too difficult or unnecessary.

Comment: Designing and implementing a programming language is a very rewarding challenge but is not an easy task. Very few languages ever "catch on" with a broader audience. I think a DSL would be an easier project and have a little better chance of being broadly used. But don't let me dissuade you from being ambitious!

Comment: If there really is not already such a project, maybe I will try to design and implement such a language. I have lots of ideas for it and I find the whole idea extremely interesting. I already started reading about LR parser and flex and bison etc. some time ago. Though these will only help me parsing the language, the ANN generation itself is new land (but I think for first versions it shouldn't be too complicated to implement optimization algorithms for generating sub ANNs for smaller statements like "ifs" or math formulas etc.)